# How to mimic -l inside script

Tags: perl

Is there a simple way to mimic the effect of the `-l` command-line switch within `perl` scripts?  (Of course, I can always `chomp` each line and then append "\n" to each line I print, but the point is to avoid having to do this.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  You can get the automatic appending of `"\n"` by using `$\`, but you have to add the chomp yourself.

Here's how `-l` works.

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -ne 'print $_'
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    print $_;
}

$ perl -MO=Deparse -lne 'print $_'
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }      # -l added this line
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    chomp $_;                        # -l added this line
    print $_;
}
```

(The comments are mine.) Notice that `-l` added a literal `chomp $_` at the beginning of the loop generated by `-n` (and it only does that if you use `-n` or `-p`).  There's no variable you can set to mimic that behaviour.

It's a little-known fact that `-l`, `-n`, and `-p` work by wrapping boilerplate text around the code you supply before it's compiled.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, try using this at the beginning of your script after the *shebang* and *strictures*:

```
$/ = $\ = "\n"; # setting the output/input record separator like OFS in awk
```

and use in the loop :

```
chomp;
print;
```

Or like this :

```
use strict; use warnings;
use English qw/-no_match_vars/;

$OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = "\n";

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    print;
}
```

I do not recommend to use

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l
```

for a better clarity =)

See [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%5C)

Comment: This provides only half of the functionality of `-l`, which also autochomps input lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to your shebang line:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l
```

Comment: Thanks!  I thought I had tried this without success, but I must have done something else wrong, because when I tried it again now it worked as one would expect.

Comment: No, I spoke too soon: the above does not work for me (auto-chomp does not happen).